# Hotplugging usb-c dock results in a new xrandr output identifier every time

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I've got a Dell WD15 hooked up to an external monitor on my desk. I connect and disconnect my laptop to this dock multiple times every day. It seems that each time I reconnect to this dock my external display shows up with a different xorg/xrandr output identifier (e.g. `DP-4`, then `DP-5`, then `DP-1-2`, etc.). This makes it difficult to have the system automatically pick up my preferred resolutions/layouts.

Is there any way to get the dock+monitor to show up with the same xorg/xrandr output identifier each time?

Comment: Hi Peter, did you figure this out? It's driving me nuts :) (with a Lenovo T490 and USB-C dock)

Comment: I worked around the issue by using a modified version of the tool grobi: https://github.com/fd0/grobi/pull/23. With that change grobi can apply a configuration based on the monitors EDID instead of the display output id.

Comment: Thanks Peter! That's a reasonable workaround, thank you. (my two Philips monitors report identical EDIDs but it's not the end of the world if they have identical setups, as long as I don't have to start from scratch. Also, resumed sessions would have apps open in the "disconnected" screens)